# How to compare a file in a project with one in the filesystem in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, compare

I have an eclipse project containing a source file. Now I have a different version of that file somewhere in the filesystem (not inside an eclipse project).

I can open the second file in eclipse, but I find no way to compare it to the first file.

**How can I compare these two files?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use WinMerge as external programm - aslo not **true way**, but *fast and simple*.

Interesting article ["Compare with" Dialog](http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_%22Compare_with%22_dialog)

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to **make a temporary copy in your Eclipse workspace**, in the same directory to make it even easier. Then compare, then delete.

Not the ideal theoretical way, but *fast and simple* to remember.

It's what I use, but I'm open to improving my ways :-)

Comment: as @KLE said, make a temporary copy of the external file to compare, select both, right click -> Compare with -> Each Other; No need to use the same directory +1

Answer (score 1):

Use the Remote System Explorer (RSE) plugin to find the files in the operating system.

Download the RSE plugin from the following link (Please check against the version of Eclipse that you are using) http://download.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/downloads/

Once installed:
1. Display your local file system in a new view by navigating: Windows -> Show View -> Other -> remote Systems -> Remote Systems

1. Use CTRL-Click to select 2 files for comparison.
2. Right-click to bring up the context menu and select Compare - To each other.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  In Eclipse Indigo, the RSE lets you browse the local filesystem, but the context menu doesn't have comparison options.

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as:

"mark first file-->right click-->select to compare"

then
"mark second file-->right click-->compare to xxxx" (xxxx is whatever you first marked)

Another useful option to keep in mind:

"mark second file-->right click-->" and have an option to mark this as first compare, in case you change your mind.

Comment: Ok Alex, would you make the dream comes true?